# xgboost feature importance vs shap values ranking interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, boosting, shapley-value

If we have two features, A and B. Feature A has a higher gain than feature B when analyzing feature importance in xgboost with `gain`. However, when we plot the shap values, we see that variable B is ranked higher than variable A.

How would you interpret that, intuitively? Because I understand from these answers:

- [Difference in model feature importance and SHAP summary plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088769/difference-in-model-feature-importance-and-shap-summary-plot)
- [Interpreting XGB feature importance and SHAP values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626523/interpreting-xgb-feature-importance-and-shap-values)

that Shap values are ranked based on how much affect the output (based on the average impact on all datapoint, I guess?). If that's the case, **shouldn't a feature with higher impact on final probability have higher gain in feature importance in xgboost?** If not, could you give an example?

My second question is, how could you explain your answer to a non-technichal stakeholder? Because it's pretty hard to see a plot with feature importances in a certain order, and then see in the shap values plot that a higher importance feature has a less impact in the output probability than a less important feature. (AKA: Could you explain in layman's terms?)

PS: [This](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/466278/machine-learning-feature-importance-method-disagreement-shap) is a kind-of similar question, but it uses `weight`, the default function of [xgboost.plot_importance()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/python/python_api.html#xgboost.plot_importance) instead of `gain`, and is unanswered yet with 3 years old (and `weight` argument is very different from the `gain` argument anyways)